# SELECT statement across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

First off, I am not an SQL coder.

I am trying to select information from 2 different tables in the same database.

Table 1 is called trans and has 3 columns:

```
CustNumb, DoT, Amount
```

Table 2 is called cust and has multiple columns:

```
CustNumb, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone
```

The SELECT statement that I'm trying to write will pull data from both tables.

```
SELECT trans.CustNumb
     , cust.Name
     , cust.City
     , cust.State
     , trans.DoT
     , trans.Amount
     , cust.Phone
     , 
  FROM trans
     , cust 
 WHERE CustNumb LIKE 1234
```

I *THINK* I need to use a JOIN statement, but I'm sure what kind of a JOIN or the proper syntax.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need a `JOIN`.  In fact, you should simply never write `,` in the `FROM` clause.

The `JOIN` you need would appear to be on the common column between the two tables:

```
SELECT t.CustNumb, c.Name, c.City, c.State, t.DoT, t.Amount, c.Phone
FROM trans t JOIN
     cust c
     ON t.CustNumb = c.CustNumb
WHERE c.CustNumb = 1234;
```

In addition, you should understand that `LIKE` is a *string* function and `1234` is not a string.  Presumably, you just want equality -- so use `=`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your answer did the trick!